# How to choose a random record from table

Tags: mysql, delphi-2010

I am trying to choose a random record from the database where the `rarity` field is `Epic.`

I have tried using the `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` but I get a syntax error.

I have also tried using the below code:

```pascal
qryCards.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tblCards WHERE Card_Rarity = "Epic"');
qryCards.Open;
Randomize;
iRandom := Random(qryCards.RecordCount);

for i := 1 to iRandom do
begin
    qryCards.Next;
end;

sCard := qryCards.FieldByName('Card_Name').AsString;
AddCards(sCard, iQtyEpic);
```

I expect the output to be a random record where the `Card_Rarity` is `Epic`.

However, I have tried debugging with `ShowMessages`, and even when `iRandom` = 2 or 3, it gives the same card, so I can never get the 2nd card.

Comment: I'm surprised that your query returns any records, because the `WHERE` clause should be `WHERE Card_Rarity = 'Epic'`, the word `Epic` being in _single_, not double, quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error with "Rand()" function in MySQL in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062201/syntax-error-with-rand-function-in-mysql-in-delphi)