# Syntax error with "Rand()" function in MySQL in Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi-2010

I am trying to use the Rand() function within MySQL to select a random record but I am getting a syntax error in the Rand() LIMIT line

```
qryCards.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tblCards WHERE Card_Rarity = "Epic"');
                  qryCards.Open;
                  iCount := qryCards.RecordCount;
                  qryCards.Close;
                  qryCards.SQL.Clear;
                  qryCards.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tblCards ORDER BY rand(' + IntToStr(iCount) + ') LIMIT 1');
                  qryCards.Open;
                  ShowMessage(qryCards.FieldByName('Card_Name').AsString);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are not using `RAND()` correctly. It returns a decimal number `0 <= N < 1`. The input value is a seed, not an upper limit like you are expecting. To get a random integer number between `0 <= N < Count`, you have to multiple the result, ie `RAND()*Count`, which you are not doing. But you don't need to do that, you can just use `RAND()` by itself, there is no need to query the record count first:

```pascal
qryCards.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tblCards WHERE Card_Rarity = "Epic" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
qryCards.Open;
ShowMessage(qryCards.FieldByName('Card_Name').AsString);
```

Otherwise, you can select a random record by specifying an offset to the `LIMIT` clause, eg:

```pascal
qryCards.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tblCards WHERE Card_Rarity = "Epic"';
qryCards.Open;
iCount := qryCards.RecordCount;
qryCards.Close;
qryCards.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tblCards WHERE Card_Rarity = "Epic" LIMIT ' + IntToStr(Random(iCount)) + ', 1');
qryCards.Open;
ShowMessage(qryCards.FieldByName('Card_Name').AsString);
```

If your table has an auto-increment id field with no gaps in it, there are other techniques you can use `RAND()` with. See [MySQL Select Random Records](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx) for examples.

Comment: I used your first solution and I get "Syntax Error: Missing operator in query expression "Rand() LIMIT 1""

Comment: @MatthewKeys what version of MySQL are you using? A similar example even appears in the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), so the syntax is fine