# How to select a random record in delphi with MySQL without using Rand()?

Tags: mysql, delphi-2010

I am trying to select a random record in a table where the "Card_Rarity is equal to a specific value, such as "Legendary". So it would check all the records where the cards are that rarity and then pick a random one and load it to the query.

I have tried using the "ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1" but I get a syntax error for some reason. I then also tried to use a for loop and use qryCards.next but that also doesn't work properly

I tried this:

```
qryCards.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tblCards WHERE Card_Rarity = "Legendary" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
```

but I get a syntax error

I also tried this:

```
 with dmCards do
   begin
     qryCards.Close;
     qryCards.SQL.Clear;

     qryCards.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tblCards WHERE Card_Rarity = "Legendary"');
     qryCards.Open;
     Randomize;
     iRandom := Random(qryCards.RecordCount) + 1;

     for i := 1 to iRandom do
       begin
         qryCards.Next;
       end;

     ShowMessage(qryCards.FieldByName('Card_Name').AsString);

 end;
```

I expect the output to be the name of a random card of that specific rarity, but the actual output is strange and I don't exactly know how to describe it. I have put ShowMessages to try and debug and when iRandom = 2 OR 3 it gives me the same card name, but if its 1 it gives me a different card. (There are only 3 legendary cards)

Comment: What is the exact error message that you're getting?

Comment: Read the result set into an array, list, etc., and then choose a random record.  This is probably your only bet given that MySQL is not working as you expect.

Comment: @MatthewKeys Why are you posting this as a new question?  [You already asked this earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062201/), and you haven't answered the latest questions asked of you there.